# Python regex for following find and replace in string

Tags: python, regex, numpy

I am trying to load large text data with to numpy arrays. Numpy's loadtxt and genfromtxt didn't work for as ,

- first, I need to remove the comment lines starting with delimiters `['#','!','C']`
- second, there is a repeat pattern in data in forms of `n*value` where `n` is an integer number of repeats and `value` is the float data.

Hence I try to read the text file using `readlines()`, then use Numpy's `loadtxt` to convert data to Numpy arrays.

For reading and replacements, I tried to use regular expressions (`re` module) but couldn't get it working. However the following Python code is working. My question is what is the most efficient and Pythonic way of doing this?

If RegEx, what is the correct regex code for following find and replace in `readlines()` list object:

```
lines = ['1 2 3*2.5 3 6 1*.3 8 \n', '! comment here\n', '1*1 2.0 2*2.1 3 6 0 8 \n']
for l, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.strip() == '' or line.strip()[0] in ['#','!','C']:
        del lines[l]        
for l, line in enumerate(lines):
    repls = [word  for word in line.strip().split() if word.find('*')>=0]
    print repls
    for repl in repls:
        print repl
        line = line.replace(repl, ' '.join([repl.split('*')[1] for n in xrange(int(repl.split('*')[0]))]))
    lines[l] = line
print lines
```

The output is following:

```
['1 2 2.5 2.5 2.5 3 6 .3 8 \n', '1 2.0 2.1 2.1 3 6 0 8 \n']
```

## Edit:

Upon comments, I edited my Python codes as follow:

```
    in_lines = ['1 2 3*2.5 3 6 1*.3 8 \n', '! comment here\n', '1*1 2.0 2*2.1 3 6 0 8 \n']
    lines = []
    for line in in_lines:
        if line.strip() == '' or line.strip()[0] in ['#','!','C']:
            continue        
        else:
            repls = [word  for word in line.strip().split() if word.find('*')>=0]
            for repl in repls:
                line = line.replace(repl, ' '.join([float(repl.split('*')[1]) for n in xrange(int(repl.split('*')[0]))]))
            lines.append(line)
    print lines
```

Comment: Don't remove lines from a list in a for loop; this will cause it to skip lines.

Comment: Loading the entire file into a list and then changing the list items in place seems like the Wrong Way to do this. For one thing, your first loop won't work because you can't delete from a list while iterating. Instead, read the file one line at a time and add the line to your list after processing it.

Comment: Is there really no newline at the end of the `'! comment here'` line?

Comment: @askewchan, my typo, there is new line character at the end of `'! comment here'`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Pythonic way

Use python's awesome functional features and list comprehension instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

lines = ['1 2 3*2.5 3 6 1*.3 8 \n', '! comment here\n', '1*1 2.0 2*2.1 3 6 0 8 \n']

#filter out comments
lines = [line for line in lines if  line.strip() != '' and line.strip()[0] not in ['#','!','C']]

#turns lines into lists of tokens
lines = [[word for word in line.strip().split()] for line in lines]

# turns a list of strings into a number generator, parsing '*' properly
def generate_numbers(tokens):
  for token in tokens:
    if '*' in token:
      n,m = token.split("*")
      for i in range(int(n)):
        yield float(m)
    else:
      yield float(token)

# use the generator to clean up the lines
lines = [list(generate_numbers(tokens)) for tokens in lines]

print lines
```

Outputs:

```
➤ ./try.py 
[[1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 3.0, 6.0, 0.3, 8.0], [1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.1, 3.0, 6.0, 0.0, 8.0]]
```

### Fast and small Pythonic way

This solution uses generators instead of lists so that you don't have to load your entire file in memory. Note the use of two idioms:

1. `with open("name") as file`

   This will clean up your file handle after you exit the block.
2. `for line in file`

   This will iterate over the lines in the file using a generator without loading up the entire file in memory.

This gives us:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# turns a list of strings into a number generator, parsing '*' properly
def generate_numbers(tokens):
  for token in tokens:
    if '*' in token:
      n,m = token.split("*")
      for i in range(int(n)):
        yield float(m)
    else:
      yield float(token)

# Pull this out to make the code more readable
def not_comment(line):
  return line.strip() != '' and line.strip()[0] not in ['#','!','C']

with open("try.dat") as file:
  lines = ( 
    list(generate_numbers((word for word in line.strip().split()))) 
    for line in file if not_comment(line)
  ) # lines is a lazy generator

  for line in lines:
    print line
```

Output:

```
➤ ./try.py 
[1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 3.0, 6.0, 0.3, 8.0]
[1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.1, 3.0, 6.0, 0.0, 8.0]
```

Comment: I like your way of using generators instead of lists, but I guess there should be a more Pythonic RegEx solutions.

Comment: There won't be a regex solution to turning `3*2.5` into `2.5 2.5 2.5`, because regexs can't count (this problem cannot be solved using regular expressions). You can use the `re` module to split the line, you can use it to find tokens and split them into subtokens, but what you're asking requires a Turing complete language, which regex aren't. I can also give you a purely functional solution, but the two above are as pythonic as it gets.

Comment: Worth noting that in Python, the purely functional solution will be harder to read than the two above, which is why I didn't bother including it. It's a joy to read in a Lisp, but that's another story...

Comment: You *can* use regexs to detect comments: `return not re.match("^\w*[!#C].*", line)`